# Making one column match the data of another column from a different table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, backend

I've made a Godot game and put it on my frontend, there are 2 things that happen database-wise when the user uses the site. Firstly he/she enters some details then they play the game and after either winning or losing the result is sent to the backend.
Currently I have two tables made in Postgres: Player and Play_Session; Player is made off the users details such as nickname etc whilst the Play_Session is made out of the game information such as the time it took for them to beat it, their reward etc. I'm trying to connect the two via Players ID and Play_Sessions userId I've made it so that if the two match everything will work as intended and if they do not that it is not a valid submissions. How would I go about doing this? I cannot use something as simple as a serial as if two players play at the same time things will fall apart and one might get the others data. Meaning I mostlikely need to alter my insert statement.
The code I have is the following:

```
export const createPlayer = async (email: string, nickname: string, address: string, number: bigint): Promise<QueryResult> => {
  return await DbConnectionManager.pool.query(`INSERT INTO ${Table.Player} (${PlayerCols.Email}, ${PlayerCols.Nickname}, ${PlayerCols.Address}, ${PlayerCols.Number}) VALUES ($1,$2, $3, $4)`,
    [email, nickname, address, number]);
}
----------
export const getPlayerData = () => {
  return DbConnectionManager.pool.query(`SELECT ${PlayerCols.Email}, ${PlayerCols.Nickname}, ${PlayerCols.Address}, ${PlayerCols.Number}, ${SessionCols.Date}, ${SessionCols.Reward}, ${SessionCols.Time} FROM ${Table.Player} P JOIN ${Table.Session} ON P.${PlayerCols.Id} = ${SessionCols.UserId}  WHERE ${SessionCols.Score} = 50 AND ${SessionCols.Date} = '2021-07-24'` )
}
```

Comment: To me it's not entirely clear what your actual problem is… Are you concerned that two players will get the same ID assigned?

Comment: Indeed, hence why I want to make 2 columns identical even though they are from different tables.
I want the primary key - Id of the Player to be set to the Session userId which is just there to track who's who. I'm not sure how to connect the two to constantly match

Comment: What you are describing is actually a fundamental concept of relational databases. The counterpart of the primary key in your player table is called a [foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-fk.html). If you need to have the ID generated on the client/frontend side one easy way is to use [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).